# Android Audio record

Tags: android

I want to know that how to record our voice and playback using AudioRecord functionality in android instead of MediaRecorder.

Please give me sample code or url.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can start by using the following prototype kind of code

```
import android.media.AudioFormat; 
import android.media.AudioRecord; 
import android.media.MediaRecorder; 
import android.util.Log; 
public class AudioListener { 
  public static final int DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE = 8000; 
  private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096; 
  private static final int CALLBACK_PERIOD = 4000;  // 500 msec (sample rate / callback   //period) 
  private final AudioRecord recorder; 
  public AudioListener() { 
    this(DEFAULT_SAMPLE_RATE); 
  } 
  private AudioListener(int sampleRate) { 
    recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT, 
        sampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_DEFAULT, 
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_DEFAULT, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE); 
  } 
  public void start() { 
    recorder.setPositionNotificationPeriod(CALLBACK_PERIOD); 
    recorder.setRecordPositionUpdateListener(new 
AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() { 
      @Override 
      public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) { 
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onMarkerReached 
Called"); 
      } 
      @Override 
      public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder) { 
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "onPeriodicNotification 
Called"); 
      } 
    }); 
    recorder.startRecording(); 
  }
```

Comment: Hi  thanks for this code.  could u pls  post this code with an activity.