# Android Mediaplayer for voice playback

Tags: android

Is there any possible that we can playback our recorded voice in android through media player with the format of wav or mp3 instead of 3gp or mp4.

if it is possible please give me a source code or  URL.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've already seen this kind of question. All yours...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165295/android-voice-recording

[Android audio and voice processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202277/android-audio-and-voice-processing)

[Android Audio record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202804/android-audio-record)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234017/android-voice-recording-in-wav-format

Please be more specific describing your problem. I think the first step would be, to show us, what you've got until now. As this is a place to solve specific problems, I would recommend you to take a look into the "What kind of questions can I ask here?" section in the https://stackoverflow.com/faq.

Answer (score 0):

3GP and MP4 are video formats. MP3/WAV are audio formats. The MediaPlayer class definitely supports both MP3 and WAV, as well as MP4 and 3GP. View [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for a list of all supported media formats on Android.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [MediaPlayer Audio](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.html) sample part of the API Demos application. You could try using this code to play your audio.